# Map direction from one country city to another

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

My Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?   saddr="+latitude_cur+","+longitude_cur+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );     
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

I can get direction within one country, But if pass Lat long from one country city to another country city, then it gives  `Message : No Route Found.`

Please help me show air direction also not only road direction.

Please any one have any idea then share it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How in the world is Google supposed to know flight routes? You will have to build that yourself by creating custom `polylines`.

Comment: Can you please share any code or link for that?